# C# WinForms Multitouch

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have been lurking for awhile and could not find an answer to my question. I am wondering if it is possible to use multitouch with C# and WinForms.

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to use one finger to move around and detect coordinates and with my other finger when it touches the screen to change a label to saying "You Clicked".

Currently I am using global hook to detect where the mouse is and I have a button on in the form that I am trying to press with the second touch.

This is a picture to better explain:
http://postimg.org/image/o2n49xtit/

I am hoping there is a way to do this with WinForms because I would like to create a on screen game pad that can have a joystick and buttons to press.

Comment: Why can't you use WPF? This is possible with win forms but requires listening to the windows message pump if I remember right.

Comment: In WPF I have searched but have not been able to find a way to easily do send keys and keep the application from being focused. Thanks very much for your help I'm honestly quite new to c# and visual studio in general and so far it seems like there is a wealth of information for WInForms vs WPF which is another reason I'd like to use WinForms